# How to append ajax result in modal with datatable

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

Good day everyone! I am trying to append my ajax result in my datatable inside my modal. I already get the data that I needed but it still shows that data is not available.

It shows like this: [image: It shows like this.]

This is my ajax success which processed the result.

```
    success: function(result)
    { 
      //console.log(result);
      //$('#viewTable').empty();
      $.each(result, function(index, value){
        console.log(value);

        $('#viewTable').append(
         '<tbody>' + 
             '<tr>' +
                '<td>' + value.qr_code + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + value.reference_no + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + value.brand_name + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + value.model_name + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + value.unitPrice + '</td>' +
             '</tr>' +
          '</tbody>'
          );
      });
```

This is my HTML

```
        <table id="viewTable" class="table table-striped">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Barcode</th>
              <th>Reference Number</th>
              <th>Brand Name</th>
              <th>Model Name</th>
              <th>Unit Price</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
        </table>
```

Note: When I uncomment the "$('#viewTable').empty();" function it will remove my thead (Datatable).

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First store the dataTable object in a variable,

```
var dataTable = $("#viewTable").DataTable();
```

Then on ajax success, [use dataTable.add([" "," ", " "]).draw()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row.add()), wherein dataTable is the variable name.

To clear the data table [use dataTable.clear();](https://datatables.net/reference/api/clear())

```
dataTable.clear().draw();
```

See code below;

```js
success: function(result) {
  // store your data table object in a variable
  var dataTable = $("#viewTable").DataTable();
  /////////////////////////////////////////////
  dataTable.clear().draw();

  $.each(result, function(index, value) {
    console.log(value);

    // use data table row.add, then .draw for table refresh
    dataTable.row.Add([value.qr_code, value.reference_no, value.brand_name, value.model_name, value.unitPrice]).draw();
  });
}
```

Comment: It works fine as I want and expected. But I only have one more concern, the data in my table is not reading my empty() function and when I clicked other view the other data is still existing which is it must not. And also, it shows an error in datatable ("DataTables warning: table id=viewTable - Cannot reinitialise DataTable. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/3")

Comment: I remove my other unnecessary code and the error in datatable is gone. I just want to empty the datatable value again when I clicked on other view.

Comment: Ah, use dataTable.clear().draw(); clear - for emptying records, draw - for refresh

Answer (score 1):

Add `<tbody>` tag to you `HTML` code as below,

```
 <table id="viewTable" class="table table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Barcode</th>
          <th>Reference Number</th>
          <th>Brand Name</th>
          <th>Model Name</th>
          <th>Unit Price</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody></tbody> <!-- New line -->
    </table>
```

Then append to `tbody` directly,

```
     $('#viewTable > tbody').append(
             '<tr>' +
                '<td>' + value.qr_code + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + value.reference_no + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + value.brand_name + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + value.model_name + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + value.unitPrice + '</td>' +
             '</tr>' +
       )
```

Comment: I already done your approached in my previous code and it doesn't work as I expected. But I appreciate your time and effort to view my post. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

So I'm not sure if you're using the DataTable jQuery plugin found here: https://datatables.net/

It almost looks like you are. I love this plugin and if you are not using it, I would definitely suggest you do use it. It's a great tool. It allows me to avoid using `.each` and `.append` as the plugin handles iterations for me.

So you have your html table grid built already so I don't need to cover that. So let's assume you have data to be called and I will go ahead and use what data points you have in your question to not confuse you. Before we start though, let's make sure of a couple of things, make sure your modal with your table is hidden. I personally use bootstrap modals as they are quick and easy. Please note I use the AJAX shorthand and hopefully that doesn't confuse you but the concept is the exact same. Fetch your data -> on success, do something with it.

```
// our html modal will have an id of mymodal
// wait for page to load
$(document).ready(()=> {
    // pretending that we have a form and you are searching by that...
    let refnum = $("#refnum").val()
    $("#dataform").submit((event)=> {
        $.get("data.php?referencenumber=" + encodeURIComponent(refnum), (data)=> {
            console.log(data)
            $("#viewTable").DataTable({
                destroy: true // allows for table to be reloaded with new data SUPER IMPORTANT!
                data: data,
                columns: [
                    // data tables iterating through the data for you
                    {'data': 'barcode'},
                    {'data': 'referencenumber'},
                    {'data': 'brandname'},
                    {'data': 'modelname'},
                    {'data': 'unitprice'},
                ]
            });
            // display hidden modal with data table. You will need to adjust the size of the modal according to how you see fit in CSS.
       $("#mymodal").slideDown(300);
        });
       event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

I hope this helps you.