# How to reload datatable in jquery using mvc

Tags: c#, jquery

I have a function and get the response from the controller.after that I need to append the details to the table.All I have done.But i can see the result only after I click the table .I think my datatable is not reloaded.How Can I solve this problem.My code is below.and html code is added here.When the select box changes according to the result the table is updated

```
     $(document).on('change', '.MemberSelect', function () {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            data: JSON.stringify({ memberTypeID: $(".MemberSelect").val() }),
            url: "@Url.Action("GetUserMenuDetails", "MenuPermission")",

            success: function (data) {
                var trHtml = '';
                $('#tblClassName tbody').empty();
                $.each(data, function (i, item) {

                    trHtml = trHtml + '<tr><td></td><td>' + (item.LibrarySchooberryMenuDetails!=null? item.LibrarySchooberryMenuDetails.MenuName : "") + '</td>'
                    '<td>' + item.MenuName + '</td>'
                    '<td><input type="checkbox" class="MenuMap" id="' + item.MenuID + '" data-id="' + item.MenuID + '"/></td>'
                    '<td><table>';
                    $.each(data.LibrarySchooberryMenuFunctions, function (j, functions) {
                        trHtml = trHtml + '<tr><td><input type="checkbox" class="FunctionMap" id="' + functions.MenuFunctionID + '"  data-id="' + functions.MenuFunctionID + '"/>'
                            + functions.Name + '<input type="hidden" value="' + functions.MenuID + '" class="menuID" /></td></tr>'

                    });
                    trHtml = trHtml + '</table></td></tr>'
                });

                $('#tblClassName').append(trHtml);
                $('#tblClassName').DataTable({
                    'paging': true,
                    'lengthChange': false,
                    'searching': true,
                    'ordering': true,
                    'info': true,
                    'autoWidth': false
                });

            },
            error: function (data) {            

            }
        });
   return false;
 });





  <div class="box-body">
                <form id="MenuPermission">


                    <div class="form-group">
                        <select class="form-control MemberSelect" name="MemberType"></select>
                    </div>

                    <div id="example1_wrapper" class="dataTables_wrapper form-inline dt-bootstrap">

                        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="tblClassName">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Sl.NO
                                    </th>
                                    <th>Parent Menu
                                    </th>
                                    <th>Menu
                                    </th>
                                    <th>Is Allowed
                                    </th>
                                    <th>Function</th>

                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                @{
                                    int i = 1;

                                    foreach (var item in Model)
                                    { 
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>@i
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LibrarySchooberryMenuDetails.MenuName)
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MenuName)
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <input type="checkbox" class="MenuMap" id="@item.MenuID" data-id="@item.MenuID"/>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <table>
                                                @foreach (var function in item.LibrarySchooberryMenuFunctions)
                                                { 
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <input type="checkbox" class="FunctionMap" id="@function.MenuFunctionID"  data-id="@function.MenuFunctionID"/>
                                                            @function.Name
                                                            <input type="hidden" value="@function.MenuID" class="menuID" />
                                                        </td>

                                                    </tr>

                                                }
                                            </table>
                                        </td>

                                    </tr>


                                    }

                                }
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
```

Comment: Can you please post your HTML code also? For which HTML element is '.MemberSelect' class is assigned?

Comment: i added the html code.select element class name is '.MemberSelect' .Can you please help me

Comment: Are you really adding another table inside the td?

Comment: Yes.I adding another table inside the td  because its a sub functions

Comment: Nothing can see after selecting the options from the select box.But if we just click the datatable we can see the result in datatable.Is that reload problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to my answer here;
[How to append ajax result in modal with datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52583381/how-to-append-ajax-result-in-modal-with-datatable/52583523#52583523)

First store the initialization to a variable, be sure to put this on the top of the script or inside a $(document).ready(function(){});

```
var dataTable = $('#tblClassName').DataTable({});
```

Instead of using jquery append to the table, you have to use the **.add()** function from the datatable object, then **.draw()** for refresh;

```
dataTable.row.Add().draw();
```

UPDATE:

```
dataTable.row.add($(trHtml)).draw();
```

To clear the datatable, use **.clear()** .

```
dataTable.clear();
```

Use this script;

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var dataTable = $('#tblClassName').DataTable({
  'paging': true,
  'lengthChange': false,
  'searching': true,
  'ordering': true,
   'info': true,
   'autoWidth': false
  });

});

$(document).on('change', '.MemberSelect', function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify({ memberTypeID: $(".MemberSelect").val() }),
        url: "@Url.Action("GetUserMenuDetails", "MenuPermission")",

        success: function (data) {
            var trHtml = '';

            // revised //////////////////////
            dataTable.clear();
            /////////////////////////////////

            $.each(data, function (i, item) {

                trHtml = trHtml + '<tr><td></td><td>' + (item.LibrarySchooberryMenuDetails!=null? item.LibrarySchooberryMenuDetails.MenuName : "") + '</td>'
                '<td>' + item.MenuName + '</td>'
                '<td><input type="checkbox" class="MenuMap" id="' + item.MenuID + '" data-id="' + item.MenuID + '"/></td>'
                '<td><table>';
                $.each(data.LibrarySchooberryMenuFunctions, function (j, functions) {
                    trHtml = trHtml + '<tr><td><input type="checkbox" class="FunctionMap" id="' + functions.MenuFunctionID + '"  data-id="' + functions.MenuFunctionID + '"/>'
                        + functions.Name + '<input type="hidden" value="' + functions.MenuID + '" class="menuID" /></td></tr>'

                });
                trHtml = trHtml + '</table></td></tr>'
            });

            // revised //////////////////////
            dataTable.row.add($(trHtml)).draw();
            /////////////////////////////////
        },
        error: function (data) {            

        }
    });
 return false;
});
```

Comment: @jasmin Did this answer the question? Do consider this as the answer